# Java substring skipping last two delimiter string

Tags: java

Any small and fastest code to get similar result ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/qqq.xml";
    String last = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    String first = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf('/'));
    String first1 = first.substring(0, first.lastIndexOf('/'));
    String first2 = first1.substring(0, first1.lastIndexOf('/'));
    System.out.println(last);
    System.out.println(first2);
}
```

Output:

```
qqq.xml
/abc/def/ghi
```

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, this looks messy.

Comment: you need file name and first three directory path?

Comment: Can you tell us the use case, maybe you're trying something, but starting on the wrong foot. This looks like analyzing the Path from a file

Comment: checkout regex exp

Comment: Do you always want this same output or are you hard coding the conditions?

Comment: Regex is one alternative. Or java nio api

Answer (score -1):

First, I would advise using File.java and some helpers from apache commons (FilenamesUtils and FileUtils)

To get filename (or as you called it 'last')  use this.

```
File myFile = new File ("some\\path\\to\\file.xml");
System.out.println(myFile.getName());
```

To get just a directory name use this

```
System.out.println(myFile.getParent());
```

Comment: How are you answer this if we don't know what is the question?

Comment: I assumed he wants to break the absolute file path string into 2 strings. One being path and other being filename. What's the big deal

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String string = "/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/qqq.xml";
        String[] arr = string.split("/");
        String first2 = String.join("/", Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,0,4));
        System.out.println(arr[arr.length-1]);
        System.out.println(first2);
    }
```

this gives the result you are looking for.
I convert the string to an array and then manipulate it